# Why can I not have the right datas inside the modal of each button?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, modal-dialog

I'm creating a task. I printed every task to be a button. A task has a title and the note. Each button will have a modal. Inside the modal will the task title and the note. Why do I keep on getting the first title and note for all modals? How can I display each of their contents? Please help.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body
{
    margin:0;
}
.submitted{
margin:0px;
}
.modal
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    display:none;
}
.modal_close
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.close
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.padding{
padding:20px 60px 60px 60px;
}
.note{
text-align:center;
}
#note{
font-family: Javanese text;
}
.call_modal{
 font-family: myFirstFont;
}
.modal_main
{
    width:50%;
    height:400px;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:16%;
    border-radius:4px;
    left:24%;
    display:none;
 -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight{0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateX(20px)}100%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:translateX(0)}}
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  font-size: 13.4px;
}
.error{
text-align:center;
padding: 170px; 50px; 50px 50px;
}
button
{
padding:20px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#808080;
border:none;
font-size:18px;
color:#fff;
margin:8%;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
      });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
      });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submitted").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");?>
<?php $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note"); ?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>

<?php
 echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
    echo '<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">'. $row['title'] . '</button>';
?>
<?php
}?>
<?php $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title, note FROM note"); ?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal_close close"></div>
<div class="modal_main">
<div class="note"> <?php

$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>


<?php
   echo '<br><br>';

       echo '<div class="padding">'.$row['title'].'';
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo ''.$row['note'].'</div>';
?>



<img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="line-height: 12px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;">
</div>
</div>
<?php
}?>
</body>
</html>
```

Each button should have modal when clicked and with the datas for each button

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your modal DIVs have the same class name 'modal_main'. In your Javascript you simply tell it to show every element with the class 'modal_main'. How does it know which modal to display?

You will need to assign some unique ID or class name to each modal, then have your JS just open the one that is needed.

Edit...

This should get you on the right track. Just think about how your click handlers can read the data-target and use that to open the correct modal. I'm out of time to write your JS as well :)

```
<?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
    $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note"); 
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { 
?>
    <button class="call_modal" data-target="<? echo $i; ?>" style="cursor:pointer;"><? echo $row['title']; ?></button>
    <div class="modal" id="modal<? echo $i; ?>">
        <div class="modal_close close"></div>
            <div class="modal_main">
                <div class="note"> 
                    <h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $row['note']; ?></p>
                    <img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="line-height: 12px; margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 2px; position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an example? ://

Comment: No, but tidied up your PHP mess ;) - look into using attr('data-target') to read the value of which modal to open..

Comment: Do you know how to do it?